# Matrix presentation of ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\left ( \begin{matrix}
    x'_1  \\
    x'_2  \\
   \end{matrix} \right ) =\left ( \begin{matrix}
    4 & 1 \\
    1 & 3 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ) \left ( \begin{matrix}
    x_1  \\
    x_2  \\
   \end{matrix} \right )
$

Is it possible to write this ode in one equation ? write if it is possible.

How am I supposed to know this ?

Thanks !

Comment: See if you can put it into controllable canonical form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process is called decoupling the equations. We have two DEs
\begin{align*} 
x_1' & = 4x_1 + x_2 \\ 
x_2' & = x_1 + 3x_2. 
\end{align*}
Differentiating the first equation once, we obtain
$$ x_1'' = 4x_1' + x_2'. $$
Substituting $x_2'$ using the second equation, we get
$$ x_1'' = 4x_1' + x_1 + 3x_2. $$
We still need to replace $x_2$, which can be done using the first equation again $x_2 = x_1' - 4x_1$. Hence,
$$ x_1'' = 4x_1' + x_1 + 3\left(x_1' - 4x_1\right)$$
or
$$ x_1'' - 7x_1' + 11x_1 = 0. $$